# Google Sheet SetValu of cell which is 2 cells ahead

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to set the value in the ebayFee cell once i enter a sold value in the sold cell.

Also, is this possible to make this function automatically so it runs every time on a new row when i enter a value to sold it automatically populate the rest for me.

```
function onEnter(num) {
 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var row = ss.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var ebayfee = ( num * 8 ) / 100;
  var cell = ss.getRange('E' + row).setValue(ebayfee);

}
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the "sold cell"? Also, sharing an example of the sheet would be helpful.

Comment: You'll probably want to use the onEdit trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, change the sheet name "Sheet1" as per your need:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  let r = e.range;
  if( r.getSheet().getName() === 'Sheet1' ) {
    if( r.rowStart >= 2 && r.columnStart === 3 ) {
      r.offset( 0, 2 ).setValue( r.getValue() * 8 / 100 );
    }
  }
};
```